# InsertionSort Program

Tags: java

In this program, i am finding the sorted array of a random array using insertion sort. So the problem i have right now is that in this program i also need to find the number of comparisons made and also the number of assignments made in this program. I've tried a bunch of ways to find the comparison and assignments. I think i have the comparison down but when i output the comparison and assignments made they should be closely equal to each other. Well in my program when i output it, it does not closely equal to well in some cases or all of them. What can i do? I dont think i am using bubble sort, unless i am...im going to have to start this from scratch.

```
/*
* To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
* and open the template in the editor.
*/
package insertionsort;
import java.util.*;
/**
 *
 * @author Owner
 */
public class InsertionSort 
    {
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
        int randomInt;
        int min;
        int max;
        int [] array;
        int random=0;
        int assign;
        int temp;  
        int comparison=0;
        int assignment=0;
        int length;
        int a;
        int k;

        System.out.print("How many random integers? ");
        randomInt=input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter the minimum: ");
        min=input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter the maximum: ");
        max=input.nextInt();
        array=new int [randomInt];

        for (a=0; a<randomInt; a++)
        {
            assign=random;
            random=(int)((Math.random()*(max-min+1)))+min;
            array[a]=random;
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("The randomized array is ");
        for(int dot=0; dot<randomInt;dot++)
        {
            if (dot==randomInt-1)
                System.out.printf("%d.", array[dot]);
            else         
                System.out.printf("%d, ",array[dot]);
        }
        System.out.println();
        length=array.length;
        for (a=1;a<length; a++)
        {
            for (int b=0; b<a;b++)
            {
                comparison++;
                if(array[b]>array[a])
                {
                    temp=array[b];
                    array[b]=array[a];
                    for (k=a;k>b;k--)
                    {
                        array[k]=array[k-1];
                        assignment++;
                    }
                    array[b+1]=temp;
                        assignment++;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.print("The sorted array is ");
        for (a=0;a<length; a++)
        {
            if (a==length-1)
                System.out.printf("%d.",array[a]);
            else
                System.out.printf("%d, ",array[a]);
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Total comparison count during sorting is " +comparison+ ".");
        System.out.println("Total assignment count during sorting is " +(assignment)+ ".");
    }
}
```

Comment: "they should be closely equal to each other" - why? If the input is already sorted you'll get comparisons but no assignments.

Comment: Sorry well first i find a number of random ints. Then i assign those to the array. Then after that i sorted them into the order i want which is least to greatest. Well inside the loop that i sorted them I need to find the count of assignments and comparisons. I dont why there wouldnt be any assignments. Im not sure why they have to be relatively equal but they always wont be equal.

Comment: Sure, but there's a chance that those random numbers will be generated already sorted. So who told you they have to be relatively equal and why do you think what you've got is wrong? It looks OK to me. If you use a large random input, e.g. 10000 elements, they'll probably tend to the same order-of-magnitude, sure.

Comment: @Rup hit the nail on the head there. They'll *tend* to be similar for larger inputs, but for smaller inputs the results can fluctuate quite a lot. If I were you, I'd take a small sampling frame, 10 or 20, and simply debug it. Step through the code and look how many assignments versus comparisons you count versus what the program counts.

Comment: Oh ok well we had this assignment and when u type in 10..with min of -50 and max of 30 the comparison came out to be 31 and the assignment count came out to be also 31 in which is similar but will not always be similar for everything. So I thought something was wrong. Thanks though :D. Also this isnt bubble sort right?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to count comparisons and assignment is to create a class that will do comparisons and assignments and use its methods instead of `<`, `>` and '='. Of course, its methods will count comparisons and assignments. Also you can wrap `int` with your class and compare/assign it with its own methods.